# How could King Janaka study Bhagavad-Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, janaka

In the Bhagavad-Gita-Mahatmya, Bhagavan Vishnu says to Dhara:

> gitAm Ashritya vahabo bhubhujo janakAdayah/nirdhutakalmashA loke gatAste paramam padam//
>
> Meaning: Many kings like Janaka washed off their sins in this world by acting according to the Gita and get liberated.

Janaka took birth in the Treta yuga,while Gita was told in the Dvapara yuga.

How could Janaka study Gita?

The same Mahatmya mentions that Gita has 745 slokas by the way and therefore  by Gita it does mean the entire Gita I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Linguistic glitch:** by acting "according to" Gita does not mean by reading Gita.
Knowledge written in Gita is there forever. (Shri Krishna in Gita says, earlier I had given this knowledge to Manu etc.)

**Referential glitch:** The Janaka being mentioned here, might be another Janaka in history, other than father of Mata Jaanki (Sita).

Comment: Thats fine. But does Gita means a couple of yogas or all the yogas?

Comment: What is a yoga?

Comment: "Gita is a collection of Yogas" - this statement is too much simplification, in my opinion.